# How can I link to a route to two components in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-routing

My application looks like (a bit simplistic):

```
<root-component>
  <div id="header>
    <header-component>
      Here are top menu items and some block (cashbox and etc).
      Depend on the route.
      Frequently one header component can be shown on many routes.
    </header-component>
    <right-menu-component>
      Here is right menu (in the right corner). Did not depend on route, always shown.
    </right-menu-component>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
     <content-component>
       Here are all content, business logic. Depend on route.
     </content-component>
  </div>
</root-component>
```

About how I see the solution (it doesn't work)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'orders', components: 
    [
      {selector: 'header-component', component: 'OrdersHeader'},
      {selector: 'content-component', component: 'OrdersComponent'}
    ]
  },
  { path: 'order-editor', components: 
    [
      {selector: 'header-component', component: 'OrdersHeader'},
      {selector: 'content-component', component: 'OrderEditorComponent'}
    ]
  },
  { path: 'some-report', components: 
    [
      {selector: 'header-component', component: 'ReportsHeader'},
      {selector: 'content-component', component: 'ReportsComponent'}
    ]
  }...
```

I want to link to header and content components to one route. I cannot put one into the other because between them is right menu and because the layout will be break.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What's your goal? Getting routed to your root component in either case?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a named outlet to change header and content routes independently of each other, e.g. content as default (unnamed) outlet and header in a named outlet:

```
<router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>
                     ^^^^^^
```

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    ...
    { path: 'header-a', component: HeaderAComponent, outlet: 'header' },
                                                              ^^^^^^
  }
```

For further information, see the docs: [Displaying multiple routes in named outlets](https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets)